# How do I search the Amazon Kindle lending library through my browser?

Tags: search, amazon, kindle

I can't figure out how I can search the subset of books available for lending. Amazon's website search appears to only have a "Kindle Store" option. And on [this help page](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200549320) I can see how one can determine whether a given book is available for lending, but there's no instructions on how to search only in the subset of lendable books. Is there anyway to search for these books on Amazon?

Answer (score 1):

I've been filtering my book searches by `Kindle Edition` and `Prime Eligible` and, so far, the search results have all been available in lending library.

The filters appear on the left sidebar after you search in the `Books` department.

For example, to see the filters, select `Books` under `All Departments` in the Search drop-down list at the top of the Amazon home page.  Enter some search terms and click the `GO` button or just click the `GO` button without any search terms.

Then select the `Kindle Edition` and `Prime Eligible` checkbox filter options located down along the left side of the page.  Note that you have to have signed-up for Prime Eligible membership to see this filter option.